# passing html data from a html file to nodeMailer

Tags: javascript, node.js, nodemailer

I have the following code using nodeMailer:

```js
const template = path.join(__dirname, '..', 'mail_templates', 'sign_up.html')
async function mailer(mailTo, subject) {
  let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    host: MAILER_HOST,
    port: MAILER_PORT,
    secure: false, // true for 465, false for other ports
    auth: {
      user: MAILER_USER, // generated ethereal user
      pass: MAILER_PASS, // generated ethereal password
    }
  })

  // send mail with defined transport object
  await transporter.sendMail({
    from: MAILER_USER, // sender address
    to: mailTo, // list of receivers
    subject: subject,
    text: 'welcome',
    html: template
  })
}
```

Is it possible to call the html file from another directory to keep the code more readable?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly and you want to user an HTML file with the message already set up, you can use the npm module [nodemailer-express-handlebars](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nodemailer-express-handlebars) to generate html template emails. For that you will have to set an html file for your template email. Considering all files in the same dir:

email_template.html :

```
<p>This is an html email template</p>
```

your mailer.js (after installing [nodemailer-express-handlebars](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nodemailer-express-handlebars)):

```
const hbs  = require('nodemailer-express-handlebars');
//...your code and transporter setup
//I don't think you should set your transporter everytime you call the mailer function so I'm considering it outside the function
async function mailer(mailTo, subject) {
    transporter.use('compile', hbs({
        viewEngine: 'handlebars',
        viewPath: './',
        extName: '.html',
    }));

    await transporter.sendMail({
      from: MAILER_USER, 
      to: mailTo,
      subject: subject,
      template: 'email_template'
    });
}
```

Comment: thanks but this not showing the html and in the email I get "./email_template" :)

Comment: I've checked the npm package description and the "template" field requires only the name of the file, not the path. I've edited the answer, check if it works now.

Comment: Thanks alot? Is it possible to send or pass a variable to template?

Comment: Since the 'template' property receives a string with the name of the template file, I suppose you could store this name as string in a variable. Also, I ask, if you think my answer solved your problem,[this post explains a bit more](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers), then accept my answer as the main answer.